# RSA character distinguishing

Tags: python

So I have just learned how RSA works and how to use it (sort of...) and I have created a script for my project that can Encrypt and Decrypt but my problem is that I Decrypt one character at a time and I don't know how to distinguish between them, right now I'm using a list to keep the characters separate but I guess that's not the proper way to do it so if anyone can give me ideas as to how I can distinguish the characters and hopefully keep them as a string I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add so example code along with desired output?

Comment: I think I’ll manage, I will add a length index before every batch of numbers so I’ll know how many represent a letter Thanks